# probability - Understanding range of probability density function

Tags: probability

Consider:$$f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}8xy & 0\le x\le y\le 1 \\0 & otherwise\end{pmatrix}$$
I want to calculate $f_X\left(x\right)$, $f_Y\left(y\right)$, the expectations of them, and $E\left[XY\right]$.

But, i don't how to determine the range of the integrals for each $f_X\left(x\right)$, $f_Y\left(y\right)$. What is the rule? (for example, for $f_X\left(x\right)$, i need to do $\int _0^1f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dy\:$ or $\int _x^1f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dy\:$?)
tnx!

Comment: Begin by sketching the plane with coordinate axes marked $x$ and $y$. Draw on your sketch the _region_ on which $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has nonzero value. Now choose your favorite value of $x$ (say $x = \frac 13$) and draw a line on the sketch through $(\frac 13,0)$ parallel to the $y$ axis. To calculate $f_X(\frac 13)$, you need to integrate the function you encounter as you traverse this line (parallel to the $y$ axis) from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Lather, rinse, repeat for other less favorite values of $x$. After spending some time doing this, you might have an Aha! moment,.... or you might not.

Comment: Yeah, this really helps me when I need to do double integrals. Although, this technique doesn't work well in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_X(x)=\int_x^1f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$. Why? If you integrate from $0$ to $1$ you are saying that $x=0$ which is not well deduced.

Comment: and what about $f_Y\left(y\right)$? how you decide?

Answer (score -1):

The definition, in this case, of the marginal distribution $F_X(x)$ is 
$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy.$$

From the domain of definition of your pdf, this simplifies to the integral $\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy$.  Do you see why?